# Film (possibly) set in Ancient Rome where a noble boy and his gladiator guardian pose as prisoners to escape assassination

Tags: identify-this-movie

While Rome is being ravaged by civil war, a noble boy seeks refuge with his guardian (formerly a seasoned gladiator or warrior).

The guardian suggests getting into the local prison. Since the boy is in threat of being assassinated, no one would look for him or another noble in a prison.

They sneak into the prison, posing as prisoners. But it's not safe in there either. The head warden tries to master dual-wielding sword technique and each day he chooses a random prisoner as his opponent. Each time he tries a specific move on the victim (Probably saw the move in a gladiator fight).

As the head warden is about to choose the boy , the boy's guardian challenges the warden. Instead of a shield, he requests another sword for his off hand (Dual-Wield is also his preferred style). They begin to duel. The warden attempts to kill the guardian with his favorite move but miserably fails as his opponent, a true master of dual-wield, quickly slices him off. In his final moments, the warden realizes the very move he tried to master, belonged to this man all along.

(My father told me about this movie so the info may be inaccurate. The duo may be Titus Pullo - Young Augustus or it may not be about Rome at all.)

Comment: Can you add any extra info about this film? What country produced it, what year was it likely released (a decade range is fine) etc... that stuff can really help narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: While I agree, the plot description is very detailed. So I'll just put up a possibility before I forget all about it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the mini-series [Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_(2005_TV_series)) from 2005 (which starred a young Emily Blunt).

> *Empire* is an American historical television series for ABC. It is an historical drama set in 44 BC Rome, and covers the struggle of a young Octavius (Santiago Cabrera), the nephew and heir of Julius Caesar, to become the first emperor of Rome. Octavius is helped in his quest by a fictitious gladiator called Tyrannus (Jonathan Cake).

Tyrannus protects young Octavius after Caesar is assassinated, and they end up in a prison [where](http://www.vernonjohns.org/snuffy1186/empire_2005.html):

> In the dungeons Octavius is selected to fight a gladiator, but Octavius won't fight.  Tyrannus steps forward.  He can't fight and win, so he lets himself get beat and falls to the ground.  There he hides his sword in the dirt.

He defeats the guard with a **dual sword technique**, as you can see in this clip (around 1:30):